# GStreamer - RTSP Stream to FLV file

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, flv

I am actually working on video streaming, the goal is to take RTSP Stream from camera and convert it to FLV file. Here is what I have tried :

```
$GSTREAMER rtspsrc location=$RTSP_SOURCE ! rtpbin ! rtph264depay ! h264parse  \
   ! avdec_h264 ! video-x/raw,width=500,height=500 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! flvmux ! filesink location=$FLV_SINK
```

The pipeline shows an error saying that it cannot use `avdec_h264` with `x264enc`, is there any alternative to avdec_h264 or x264enc that can be used together ? or is there any alternative way to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `video-x/raw,width=500,height=500`. You cannot dictate the video resolution like that without a video scale element.

If scaling is desired add a `videoscale` element. Make sure your output dimensions are compatible with the codec and the element will handle.

Select width and height that is a multiple of 16 to be on the safe side.

```
$GSTREAMER rtspsrc location=$RTSP_SOURCE ! rtpbin ! rtph264depay ! h264parse  \
   ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale ! video-x/raw,width=640,height=640 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! flvmux ! filesink location=$FLV_SINK
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it helped me to get rid of the error, but resize is required, where should I put that in the pipeline ? Whay is the correct way ?

Comment: Put a `videoscale` element between `avdec_h264` and your `video/x-raw ..` caps

Comment: Did that, but it says `could not  link videoscale0 to x264enc`

Comment: It may be due to format limitations. Perhaps 500x500 is not acceptable for x264. Use GST_DEBUG=4 and read on about the caps negotiation and why it fails.

Comment: Is that because of `x264enc`, in many answers people are using `avenc_h264_omx` instead, I dont have it available

Comment: No, the OMX variant is found only on some embedded platforms. The codec, H.264 has some limitations. Resolutions with a multiple of 16 for example maybe help.. but check the log that it actually tries to do. Maybe you need a color space conversion too.

Comment: Making video width and height multiples of 16 worked! Thanks, can you please edit the answer to include it so it will be helpful for others :)